# Ошибка: [Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 5, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 0]

Tags: java, android, firebase, storage

Проверяю кучу файлов (>1000) на наличие их на FireBase Storage.
Для проверки регистрирую Listener:

```
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("Путь к файлу");
riversRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
    uriItems.add(new UriItems(uri, di.getName()));
  }               
)}
```

И тут сталкиваюсь с проблемой, т.к. файлов много, вылетает Exeption:

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   com.google.firebase.storage.zzb@63b9dea rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1629f78[Running, pool size =
>   5, active threads = 5, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 0]

То есть, на каждый файл регистрируется отдельный поток и когда количество потоков достигает 128 шт. приложение крашится.

Вопрос в следующем, есть ли возможность приостановить работу метода, не тормозя при этом работу основного потока, для того что бы вызванные Listener'ы могли завершить свою работу.

Или может подскажете какой нибудь другой способ решения данной проблемы.

Comment: А где код самого запуска потоков?

Comment: Я полагаю это делается в этой строчке riversRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()

Comment: Очень маленький пул потоков, но и такое количество задач тоже не норма, плодить столько потоков - плохая идея.

Comment: Я такого же мнения. Вот и спрашиваю, если есть возможность приостановить, к примеру, отдельно взятый цикл `for`, то я бы подождал пока первые 20 потоков завершится, затем бы продолжил цикл и т.д. Хотя, конечно, это звучит как то очень фантастически )

Comment: Есть такие способы, я тут полотно кода сейчас не смогу накидать, но многопоточность тогда нужно самому организовывать, все инструменты для этого лежат в java.util.concurrent

Comment: @A-Z, спасибо, буду что нибудь думать )